# Wordpress: Way to just display forth navigation level?

Tags: wordpress

is there a way in wordpress to just display the forth navigation level when i'm on the third level?

thanks!

Comment: Do you wants to display the forth level navigation on main menu or somewhere on the sidebar or page??

Comment: i want to display the forth level in the content area, so NOT in the main page navigation!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  if($post->post_parent) {
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
  $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
  }

  else {
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
  $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->ID);
  }
  if ($children) { ?>

  <h2> <?php echo $titlenamer; ?> </h2>
  <ul>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>

<?php } ?>
```

This code will display all the child pages of current page. So when you are on level 3, It will display the level 4 sub-pages if exists.

[**Refer this Codex section**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_Sub-Pages)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function:

```
function getPages($pid=0) {
    global $wpdb;
    $pages = $wpdb->get_results($sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE
            post_type = 'page' &&
            post_status = 'publish' &&
            post_parent = $pid
        ORDER BY menu_order
    ");
    return $pages;
}
```

$pid is parent id in your case third navigation level pages id.